# What can I add to my .gitignore so that I can prevent checking in pods on my github repo?

Tags: ios, xcode, github, gitignore, cocoapods

I am looking to transition to checking in only the podfile in my Github repo instead of constantly checking in every single pod whenever I run a pod install. . right now my gitignore code CocoaPods looks like this looks like this

```
    Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.markdown
    Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.plist
    Pods/resources-to-copy.txt
    Pods/resources-to-copy-*.txt
```

I am still getting a ton of xcconfig files from Cocoapods that are being checked in. help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how your files are structured. But you should just be able to add Pods/* to your .gitignore and then when you want to add a specific file to git use:

```
git add Pods/IWANTTHISFILE --force
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: hmm - i just tried that, but i'm still getting the xcconfig files (relative to their pods) showing up on check in.. any ideas, or even where i should be looking into??

Comment: If you want to ignore everything inside a directory, you should probably either use `Pods/` or `Pods/**`, rather than `Pods/*`.

Answer (score 5):

To ignore just the sub folders of Pods proj file:

```
Pods/*.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/
Pods/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
```

To ignore everything inside Pods folder

```
Pods/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following and your problem is solved:

```
    Pods/
```